# How would I perform this text pattern matching

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, pattern-matching, boost-spirit

*Migrated from [[Spirit-general](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Pattern-matching-with-boost-tt4021341.html)] list*

<sub><sup>Good morning,</sup></sub>

I'm trying to parse a relatively simple pattern across 4 `std::strings`,
extracting whatever the part which matches the pattern into a separate
`std::string`.

In an abstracted sense, here is what I want:

```
s1=<string1><consecutive number>, s2=<consecutive number><string2>,
s3=<string1><consecutive number>, s4=<consecutive number><string2>
```

Less abstracted:

```
s1="apple 1", s2="2 cheese", s3="apple 3", s4="4 cheese"
```

Actual contents:

```
s1="lxckvjlxcjvlkjlkje xvcjxzlvcj wqrej lxvcjz ljvl;x czvouzxvcu
j;ljfds apple 1 xcvljxclvjx oueroi xcvzlkjv; zjx", s2="xzljlkxvc
jlkjxzvl jxcvljzx lvjlkj wre 2 cheese", s3="apple 3", s4="kxclvj
xcvjlxk jcvljxlck jxcvl 4 cheese"
```

How would I perform this pattern matching?

Thanks for all suggestions,

Alec Taylor

**Update 2**

> Here is a really simple explanation I just figured out to explain the
>   problem I am trying to solve:
>
> ```
>  std::string s1=garbagetext1+number1+name1+garbagetext4;
>  std::string s3=garbagetext2+(number1+2)+name1+garbagetext5;
>  std::string s5=garbagetext3+(number1+4)+name1+garbagetext6;
> ```

---

<sub>**Edit** for context:</sub>

> *Feel free to add it to stackoverflow (I've been having some trouble
>   posting there)*
>
> *I can't give you what I've done so far, because I wasn't sure if it
>   was within the capabilities of the boost::spirit libraries to do what
>   I'm trying to do*

Comment: Sehe, I didn't notice in the original thread what exactly Alec wants the _output_ to be for his complicated inputs. Can you re-work his post a little bit with your crystal ball to figure out what he's after?

Comment: In the example "abstracted" data, the string always starts or ends with a number; in the "actual contents" data, it doesn't. Can you show what the expected output of the actual content is?

Comment: @sarnold: I have just posted my 'crystal ball picture image' of it... I'll cross post that to the list for the beneficiary :)

Comment: @sehe: wow. That's an _amazing_ crystal ball you've got. :)

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**: Re ***Update2***

> Here is a really simple explanation I just figured out to explain the
>   problem I am trying to solve:
>
> ```
> std::string s1=garbagetext1+number1+name1+garbagetext4;
> std::string s3=garbagetext2+(number1+2)+name1+garbagetext5;
> std::string s5=garbagetext3+(number1+4)+name1+garbagetext6;
> ```

It starts looking like a job for:

- Tokenizing the 'garbage text/names' - you could make a symbol table of sorts on the fly and use it to match patterns (spirit Lex and Qi's symbol table (`qi::symbol`) could facilitate it, but I feel you could write that in any number of ways)
- conversely, use regular expressions, as suggested before ([below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074103/how-would-i-perform-this-text-pattern-matching/8074220#8074220), and at least twice in mailing list).

Here's a simple idea:

```
 (\d+) ([a-z]+).*?(\d+) \2
```

- `\d+`        match a sequence of digits in a "(*subexpression*)" (`NUM1`)
- `([a-z]+)`   match a *name* (just picked a simple definition of 'name')
- `.*?`        skip any length of garbage, but as little as possible before starting subsequent match
- `\d+`        match another number (sequence of digits) (`NUM2`)
- `\2`         followed by the **same** *name* (**[backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)**)

You can see how you'd already be narrowing the list of matches to inspect down to 'potential' hits. You'd only have to /post-validate/ to see that NUM2 == NUM1+2

Two notes:

1. Add `(...)+` around the tail part to allow **repeated** matching of patterns

   ```
     (\d+) ([a-z]+)(.*?(\d+) \2)+
   ```
2. You may wish to make the garbage skip (`.*?`) aware of separators (by doing **[negative zerowidth assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)**) to avoid more than 2 skipping delimiters (e.g. `s\d+="` as a delimiting pattern). I leave it out of scope for clarity now, here's the gist:

   ```
   ((?!s\d+=").)*?         -- beware of potential performance degradation
   ```

---

Alec, The following is a show-case of how to do a wide range of things in Boost Spirit, in the context of answering your question.

I had to make assumptions about what is required input structure; I assumed

- whitespace was strict (spaces as shown, no newlines)
- the sequence numbers *should* be in increasing order
- the sequence numbers *should* recur exactly in the text values
- the *keywords* 'apple' and 'cheese' are in strict alternation
- whether the *keyword* comes before or after the the sequence number in the text value, is also in strict alternation

**Note** There are about a dozen places in the implementation below, where significantly less complex choices could possibly have been made. For example, I could have hardcoded the whole pattern (as a *de facto regex*?), assuming that 4 items are always expected in the input. However I wanted to

- make no more assumptions than necessary
- learn from the experience. Especially the topic of [`qi::locals<>` and *inherited attributes*](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/nonterminal/rule.html) have been on my agenda for a while.

However, the solution allows a great deal of flexibility:

- the *keywords* aren't hardcoded, and you could e.g. easily make the parser accept both keywords at any sequence number
- a comment shows how to generate a custom parsing exception when the sequence number is out of sync (not the expected number)
- different spellings of the sequence numbers are currently accepted (i.e. `s01="apple 001"` is ok. Look at [Unsigned Integer Parsers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/numeric/uint.html) for info on how to tune that behaviour)
- the output structure is either a `vector<std::pair<int, std::string> >` or a vector of struct:

  ```
  struct Entry
  {
      int sequence;
      std::string text;
  };
  ```

  both versions can be switched with the single `#if 1/0` line

The sample uses Boost Spirit Qi for parsing.
Conversely, Boost Spirit Karma is used to display the result of parsing:

```
format((('s' << auto_ << "=\"" << auto_) << "\"") % ", ", parsed)
```

The output for the ***actual contents*** given in the post is:

```
parsed: s1="apple 1", s2="2 cheese", s3="apple 3", s4="4 cheese"
```

On to the code.

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace karma = boost::spirit::karma;
namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

#if 1 // using fusion adapted struct

    #include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
    struct Entry
    {
        int sequence;
        std::string text;
    };

    BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Entry, (int, sequence)(std::string, text));

#else // using boring std::pair

    #include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp> // for karma output generation
    typedef std::pair<int, std::string> Entry;

#endif

int main()
{
    std::string input =
        "s1=\"lxckvjlxcjvlkjlkje xvcjxzlvcj wqrej lxvcjz ljvl;x czvouzxvcu"
        "j;ljfds apple 1 xcvljxclvjx oueroi xcvzlkjv; zjx\", s2=\"xzljlkxvc"
        "jlkjxzvl jxcvljzx lvjlkj wre 2 cheese\", s3=\"apple 3\", s4=\"kxclvj"
        "xcvjlxk jcvljxlck jxcvl 4 cheese\"";

    using namespace qi;

    typedef std::string::const_iterator It;

    It f(input.begin()), l(input.end());

    int next = 1;
    qi::rule<It, std::string(int)> label;
    qi::rule<It, std::string(int)> value;
    qi::rule<It, int()>            number;
    qi::rule<It, Entry(), qi::locals<int> > assign;

    label  %= qi::raw [ 
                  ( eps(qi::_r1 % 2) >> qi::string("apple ")  > qi::uint_(qi::_r1) )
               |   qi::uint_(qi::_r1) > qi::string(" cheese")
       ];

    value  %= '"' 
        >> qi::omit[ *(~qi::char_('"') - label(qi::_r1)) ]
        >> label(qi::_r1)
        >> qi::omit[ *(~qi::char_('"'))         ]
        >> '"';

    number %= qi::uint_(phx::ref(next)++) /*| eps [ phx::throw_(std::runtime_error("Sequence number out of sync")) ] */;

    assign %= 's' > number[ qi::_a = _1 ] > '=' > value(qi::_a);

    std::vector<Entry> parsed;

    bool ok = false;
    try
    {
        ok = parse(f, l, assign % ", ", parsed);

        if (ok)
        {
            using namespace karma;
            std::cout << "parsed:\t" << format((('s' << auto_ << "=\"" << auto_) << "\"") % ", ", parsed) << std::endl;
        }
    } catch(qi::expectation_failure<It>& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Expectation failed: " << e.what() << " '" << std::string(e.first, e.last) << "'" << std::endl;
    } catch(const std::exception& e)
    { 
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl; 
    }

    if (!ok || (f!=l))
        std::cerr << "problem at: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Provided you can use c++11 compiler, parsing these patterns is pretty simple using AXE<sup>†</sup>:

```
#include <axe.h>
#include <string>

template<class I>
void num_value(I i1, I i2)
{
    unsigned n;
    unsigned next = 1;
    // rule to match unsigned decimal number and compare it with another number
    auto num = axe::r_udecimal(n) & axe::r_bool([&](...){ return n == next; });
    // rule to match a single word
    auto word = axe::r_alphastr();
    // rule to match space characters
    auto space = axe::r_any(" \t\n");

    // semantic action - print to cout and increment next
    auto e_cout = axe::e_ref([&](I i1, I i2) 
    { 
        std::cout << std::string(i1, i2) << '\n'; 
        ++next; 
    });

    // there are only two patterns in this example
    auto pattern1 = (word & +space & num) >> e_cout;
    auto pattern2 = (num & +space & word) >> e_cout;

    auto s1 = axe::r_find(pattern1);
    auto s2 = axe::r_find(pattern2);
    auto text = s1 & s2 & s1 & s2 & axe::r_end();
    text(i1, i2);
}
```

To parse the text simply call `num_value(text.begin(), text.end());` No changes required to parse unicode strings.

<sup>†</sup> I didn't test it.

Comment: Looking very interesting. You don't seem to have something in place to check for matching words, yet? Also Re: `† I didn't test it` -- You also didn't link to it. Googling `axe.h` or `"Axe Library"` comes up empty/unhelpful? I noticed that you posted other answers based on Axe, but I found no link yet. Also, do you have sample output? Without lib and without documentation, I'm left to guess what `s1 & s2 ... ` does (and `auto` doesn't clue us in, either).

Comment: @sehe -- sorry, I thought it was easy to find the library. Here is one place to get it: tinyurl.com/724jfkt

Comment: @sehe -- I now tested it, found a bug in r_find, fixed it, it now prints "apple 1\n2 cheese\napple 3\n4 cheese" as one would expect. So thanks for the new test case :-)

Comment: if you're using C++11 doesn't that already have <regex> which in and of itself you can do pattern matching with (rather than needing to pull in a third party lib (I'm assuming AXE is third party))?

Answer (score 0):

Look into Boost.Regex. I've seen an almost-identical poosting in boost-users and the solution is to use regexes for some of the match work.

Comment: Could you dig up a reference? If it is any good, I'm prepared to accept your answer, especially after the most recent shift in the question.